# While working with negative slopes, how to decide which slope is greater?

Tags: functions, slope, number-line

For an example, we take two lines L1 and L2. L1 makes 130 degrees with +ve X axis and has slope m1=tan(130 degrees)= -1.17. Similarly, L2 makes 150 degrees with +ve X axis and has slope m2= -0.577.

Here, clearly m1 < m2 but the steepness of L1 is greater than L2. So, do I go with L1 has greater steepness thus greater slope or L2 has greater slope(greater numerical value) ?

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/2ww4l3/when_comparing_negative_slopes_is_the_largest_one/) on reddit but still wanted some more information.

Comment: You can say that the line whose slope is larger in absolute value is steeper. I wouldn't say it has greater slope, contradicting the numerical meaning of "greater". If you find this written somewhere it's not necessarily terrible. It might be clear, but just make mathematicians uncomfortable.

Comment: I'd avoid saying "greater slope" altogether.  As slope is a real number value $y= mx + b$ has "greater slope" than $y = nx + c$ can not logically mean anything except $m > n$ which... isn't particularly interesting or useful.   And the term "greater slope" is certainly misleading as it *sounds* like "steeper" which is certainly doesn't mean.

Answer (score 0):

130 degree line has greater steepness so it's slope is greater than 150 degree line. Draw these two line you will get answers yourself.

Or take modulus of |tan130|>|tan150|